# Most polyominoes in an 8x8 grid

Tags: geometry, optimization, polyomino

What is the most number of distinct free [polyominoes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino) you can form by painting an 8x8 grid in two colours? Here a polyomino is a set of orthogonally adjacent cells of the same colour, so polyominoes of the same colour cannot share an edge. Two free polyominoes are considered distinct if they are not a rigid transformation (translation, rotation, reflection, glide-reflection) of each other. Polyominoes of the same shape, but different colours are **not** considered distinct.

Comment: Please update the description to specify that polyominoes of the same color cannot share an edge and also to clarify whether polyominoes of different colors are considered distinct.

Comment: Added the requested clarifications.

Comment: Are zero-square polyominoes allowed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I believe <s>14</s> 15 is the best possible (but I can't quite rule out 16). 
>  Edit: OK, I found a solution with 16. This matches the knapsack upper bound and is definitely optimal:
>  
>  16:
>  [image: 16]
>  
>  15:
>  [image: 15]
>  
>  14:
>  [image: 14]

Comment: This is very nice work! I am particularly impressed that you got some hexominoes in there.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Thanks. I actually found that 15 is possible.

Comment: wow 15 is incredible! There are some big ones (including an 8), so I feel that 16 is possible...

Comment: For example a white vertical domino can fit in the bottom right without affecting the count

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Yes, you were right.

Comment: What is this knapsack upperbound you speak of?

Comment: @justhalf Think greedy algorithm. You have 1x polyomino with 1 piece, 1 with 2, 2 with 3, 5 with 4 ... so you first take smaller and then go towards bigger ones. You can easily see that 16th will get total area to 64 already so you cannot possibly squeeze one more.

Comment: Ah, noted. Thanks Zizy

Comment: The solution you posted could equally have 17 unique polyominoes as there is technically a polyomino with 0 squares: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polyomino+order+0

Answer (score 12):

If polyominoes of the same color can share an edge and polyominoes of different colors are considered distinct, the maximum is

> 19, with 2 each of the 9 free polyominoes of size at most 4, and 1 free pentomino:
>  [image]

Under the intended interpretation (polyominoes of the same color cannot share an edge and polyominoes of different colors are not considered distinct), the maximum is

> 16:
>  [image]

If polyominoes of the same color cannot share an edge and polyominoes of different colors are considered distinct, the maximum is

> 19:
>  [image]

Comment: As I read the problem I thought that two polyominoes of the same color could not share an edge.  Otherwise the restriction to two colors does not matter as your solution shows.  This is a good solution to another problem, so +1

Comment: Actually Ross is correct - that was my original intention of the problem. This solution is still interesting though, so +1.

Comment: This is also a great answer, but I am accepting the other one as it was earlier.

Answer (score -3):

Controversial answer:

> You can fit 17 polyominoes in an 8x8 grid actually, since (arguably) there is a polyomino with *****zero***** squares.[image: Technically 17 tetrominoes]

Credits to @RobPratt for image.

Comment: According to wikipedia, "A polyomino is a plane geometric figure formed by joining **one or more** equal squares edge to edge"

Comment: @ACB there isn’t a citation, it might be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I've never heard of a polyomino with zero cells

Comment: @ACB [The OEIS says otherwise.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706305/1022719)